# Android ViewPager Refresh fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

In my app there's 2 tabs (Android Design Support Library) this is the Fragment with ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ListaCanali extends Fragment {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 2 ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_canali, container,false);

    //Titolo Fragment
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Lista Canali");

    //FindViewById
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    //Funzioni Tab
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return v;
}


//Adattatore Tab
class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return new FragmentCanali();
            case 1 : return new FragmentPreferiti();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Tutti";
            case 1 :
                return "Preferiti";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I want my app refresh fragment on Swipe and on click the tabs title because this don't happen, I hope you can help me guys.

Comment: you can check [this example](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/RefreshCurrentFragmentWithinViewPager)

Comment: Thanks for `getChildFragmentManager()`. I replaced `getFragmentManager()` with it in my project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure this is not the only/best way to do it. But this should solve the problem as it did to me.

Please write refresh() methods in both 
FragmentCanali and FragmentPreferiti Fragments.

```
    public class ListCanali extends Fragment implements OnPageChangeListener{
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View OnCreateView (...) {
    ...
    if(mAdapter == null) {
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    }
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    ...
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void OnPageSelected (int position) {
    switch (position){
            case 0 : ((FragmentCanali)adapter.getItem(position)).refresh();
            case 1 : ((FragmentPreferiti)adapter.getItem(position)).refresh();
        }
    }}
```

It will be cleaner if you extend both the fragments from a base fragment which has abstract refresh() method.

In the onPageSelected() you can just call `((BaseFragment)adapter.getItem(position)).refresh()`

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

**To Refresh** a fragment you need it's instance first.

change this

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```

to

```
 ArrayList<Fragment> fr_list = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
 fr_list.add(new FragmentCanali());
 fr_list.add(new FragmentPreferiti());
 MyAdapter mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),fr_list);
 viewPager.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);
```

In adapter change this

```
 public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    switch (position){
        case 0 : return new FragmentCanali();
        case 1 : return new FragmentPreferiti();
    }
    return null;
}

public int getCount() {

    return int_items;

}
```

to

```
 public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<Fragment> fr_list) {
    super(fm);
    this.fr_list=fr_list;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{     
        return fr_list.get(position);
}

public int getCount() {

    return fr_list.size();

}
```

add refresh() methods inside the fragments and call it whenever you need like below

```
((FragmentCanali) mMyAdapter.fr_list.get(0)).refresh();
```

Comment: hello, thank you but show me error... screen: [Click HERE](http://cineblog01.be/cattura.png)

Comment: Ok i solved but i have new error: [CLICK HERE](http://www.cineblog01.be/screen.png)

Comment: add this line in your adapter ArrayList<Fragment> fr_list;

Comment: i have already add the line look at the screen. What's fr_list? Can you edit and put my fragment in the example?

Comment: Change `((FragmentCanali)fr_list.get(0)).refresh();` to `((FragmentCanali)mMyAdapter.fr_list.get(0)).refresh();`, where `mMyAdapter` is your member variable for the adapter.