# How to refresh the Pager tab fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have to refresh the `fragment` when I swipe to another `fragment` from the Tab.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.manage_work_shop_act, container, false);


    mBinding.layout.title.setText(getString(R.string.d_manage_my_staff));

    mBinding.tabs.setupWithViewPager(mBinding.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(mBinding.viewpager);

    mBinding.layout.nav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mBinding.layout.navMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mBinding.layout.navMenu.setOnClickListener(view -> openDrawer());

    return mBinding.getRoot();
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    int limit = (adapter.getCount() > 1 ? adapter.getCount() - 1 : 1);

    adapter.addFragment(new MechanicListFragment(), getString(R.string.d_manage_my_staff));
    adapter.addFragment(new MechanicNewFragment(), getString(R.string.new_frag));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My Adapter is like this

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
}
```

I tried all the ways to refresh my `fragment`. 
If I swipe the tab or click the another tab then I need to refresh the visible tab again. 
In my current `fragment` did not refresh.

please help me to override from this issue.

Comment: Post your adapter code also.Try using Fragment state pager adapter than fragment adapter if you are using.

Comment: check this link my friend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32435250/android-viewpager-refresh-fragment

Comment: I have updated my adapter class please check

Comment: View pager will load at the same time Left and Right items. So total 3 view pager item will load by default. So if you are swiping within that range it will not recreate the pager item. if you want to refresh manually, reload your fragment on view pager ItemSelected method.

Comment: Can you give me an example for this ?

Comment: do refreshing in @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser){
            
        }
    }

Comment: where to add this ?

Comment: In your fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try using Fragment state pager adapter than fragment adapter when you have to refresh tabs in your adapdter.

FragmentPagerAdapter stores the previous data which is fetched from the adapter while FragmentStatePagerAdapter takes the new value from the adapter everytime it is executed.

Comment: I have changed like this 
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

It's not working

Answer (score 0):

There's [onHiddenChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean)) method in the fragment.

> Called when the hidden state (as returned by isHidden() of the
>   fragment has changed. Fragments start out not hidden; this will be
>   called whenever the fragment changes state from that.

override the `onHiddenChanged` method in each of your tab fragment and if is not hidden do the refreshing. For example:

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
        if (!hidden) {
            //you can refresh here now
        }
    }

}
```